# Push Notification on Test Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications, urbanairship.com

I have implemented Urban Airship for push notifications.  namedUser.identifier is being recognised through the Urban Airship dashboard but it says the device is not opted-in.

Could this be down to the fact that it is being run on a test device (not simulator) and has not been signed with a valid certificate with notifications enabled (client signs the app so don't access).

If the app is not signed with the correct certificate will notifications always be disabled?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it may be a certificates related problem, but be sure to check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Because you have to register your app for remote notifications, if you didn't already. You could do it like this, for instance:

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
             UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

Comment: Although this could be the answer you should provide more specific info/instructions/CODE to solve the user problem.